# How to search the inbox based on the subject and filter the message

Tags: java, jmeter-5.0

With javamail how can I search the gmail based on the "Subject" and filter the message based on "Has the words"? Gmail provides this option in the search email option. How can I implement this in the JMeter JSR223 Sampler?
In this case the search will result only one email when the search criteria apply, which I want to assign to a string variable by `SampleResult.getResponseDataAsString()`

[image]